# Activity does not load until ad has loaded first. How can I make an activity load first before admob ad

Tags: android, admob

And if there's no Internet connection the activity just stays black as if it's loading. How can I make sure the activity loads first?

Comment: give us some code, how can you use admob?

Answer (score 0):

Use threads: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html , Declare this as a global variable: `Handler mHandler = new Handler();` 
and then this in the place you need:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            try {
                //waits 10 sec. to load the admob, enough time 
                //to load the activity
                Thread.sleep(10000); 
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Write your code here to the admob
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```